# About the symmetry protected issue at Dirac point in graphene

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, graphene

I have studied several resources about the band structure of graphene. They always mention that the Dirac point in graphene is protected by time reversal symmetry and inversion symmetry. I can understand that inversion symmetry corresponds to the same on-site energy (in other words, it has the same element in the 2x2 Hamiltonian kernel) we will always have a solution for the zero energy band gap. If they are different, it breaks inversion symmetry, and we can explicitly solve for the eigenvalue of the kernel and show it explicitly that it is impossible to have a zero band gap solution when the upper band subtract the lower one. My question is: how does one show that the Dirac point in graphene is also protected by time reversal symmetry? As I know, the time reversal operator is an antiunitary operator which gives a complex conjugation or we can flip the sign of the time variable or the k variable, but how can we show explicitly that the zero band gap is one of the consequences of time reversal symmetry?

Comment: Try to explicitly construct the time reversal symmetry operator (T), and then consider the effect of those terms that do not commute with T on the band structure.